# Checking value from Combobox(string) without ToString C#

Tags: c#

I'm doing a project where "ToString" is being used as a method.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(cboPlaneType.SelectedItem = "Generic")
    {
    }
    else if (cboPlaneType.SelectedIndex = "Passenger")
    {
    }
    else if (cboPlaneType.SelectedIndex = "Fighter Jet")
    {
    }
}
```

And in this case i'm not sure what to do. As you can see I've tried a few different option but with no avail. I've also tried 
`if((string)cboPlaneType.SelectedItem = "Generic")`
And that didn't work.

**Edit
Just to point out, SelectedValue wasn't the correct answer.
ended up being "`if((string)combobox.SelectedItem == "Generic")`

Comment: What do you mean with *"where "ToString" is being used as a method"*? Also, the above code would not compile (since you do assignments and not comparisons in the if-statements). What is it that you are trying to achieve, really?

Comment: Depending on the selected value i'm suppose to display certain information in a label off to the side of the main form. I just mean that it's being overridden.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equality operator in c# is `==`; `=` is an assignment operator.

`SelectedIndex` will return an `int` representing the zero-based position of the item that is selected. (I'm guessing it returns -1 when no item is selected.)

`SelectedItem` can be an object of any type; if it is not a string then you can't match it by comparing with a string.

Are you saying that the objects with which the `ComboBox` is populated override `ToString()`? You should still be able to use the result of that method for comparison, because it can only return a `string`. Otherwise, you might be able to use `SelectedValue`, but this depends on what kind of `ComboBox` you are using and how you have set it up.

Comment: In another section of the program ToString was overridden and couldn't be used. And It was the == that was the issue. I ended up with 
"if((string)cboPlaneType.SelectedValue == "Generic")"

Answer (score 1):

`SelectedIndex` is an property of type `Int32`.
Maybe you want to use `SelectedValue` instead ?

Comment: "Error 3 Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'bool'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)"
When i try and do that.

Comment: use the == operator (equality operator), not the = operator (affectation)