# error when runnign the form: Possible unintended referenece comparision; to get a value comparision, cast the left hand side to type 'string'

Tags: c#

i have use the combo box: Two selection only: "Jewelry", "Gem"

this is my code :

```
private void combo_main_type_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (combo_main_type.SelectedItem == "Jewelry")
        {
            txt_qty.Visible = true;
            label6.Visible = true;
            txt_qty.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(400, 400);
            label6.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(550, 500);
        }
        else
        {
            txt_qty.Visible = false;
            label6.Visible = false;
        }


    }
```

this line is underlined by red color: if (combo_main_type.SelectedItem == "Jewelry")

Comment: What's the type of `combo_main_type.SelectedItem`?  It sounds like you want to get a string *from* that object, not compare to the object *itself*.

Comment: Show us the code that puts the items into the combo box

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Checking value from Combobox(string) without ToString C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4876013/checking-value-from-comboboxstring-without-tostring-c-sharp)

Comment: this textbox visibility is working fine and when running the form its not asking for errordebug it just works fine. But only this line: if (combo_main_type.SelectedItem == "Jewelry") is underlined red color

Answer (score 1):

Compare it against `SelectedText` instead:

```
if (combo_main_type.SelectedText == "Jewelry")
```

#### `SelectedText`

> A string that represents the currently selected text in the combo box. If DropDownStyle is set to DropDownList, the return value is an empty string ("").

Answer (score -1):

`.SelectedItem` is an `object` and you are comparing to a `string`. Add a cast to `string` before you compare the two. It even says so in the warning `...cast the left hand side to type 'string'`

```
if ((string)combo_main_type.SelectedItem == "Jewelry")
```

Comment: SelectedItem has Selected Value and SelectedTExt you need to choose one of those properties

Comment: @gh9 **Wrong!** If you know the `.SelectedItem` is going to be a string this will work. I've tested it before posting. The above code works as expected!

Comment: thank you so much the above code of your works fine,.

Comment: @MohammedAlthaf Don't forget to accept/vote for a satisfying answer.